# RXJS scan returning one item, expecting multiple

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I am trying to turn a stream of observables into an array and despite trying different approaches I seem to get the same behaviour.  As a newbie I'm expecting the scan in the createOwners call to return the 10 owners as an array.  The behaviour I'm actually getting is it returns an array of the last item.  I have tried to use toArray() and it produces the same result but the scan allows me to instrument the code a little better.

I'm obviously misunderstanding something quite integral so please let me know why the scan results in an array of 1 item rather than 10.

```
public put(ownerModel: OwnerModel): Observable<OwnerModel> {
   console.log('put ' + ownerModel.name);
   const  o = this.storageModel.put(ownerModel);
   console.log('put.finished ' + ownerModel.name);
   return o as Observable<OwnerModel>;
}


public createOwners(numberOfOwners: number, isUser: boolean, game: GameModel): Observable<OwnerModel[]> {
return Observable.range(0, numberOfOwners)
        .do(counter => '1 ' + counter)
        .map(counter => NameService.GeneratePersonName())
        .do(val => console.log('2 ' + val))
        .map(personName => OwnerModel.GenerateModel(personName, NumberService.GenerateRandomNumber(60), isUser, game))
        .do(owner => console.log('3 ' + (owner as OwnerModel).name))
        .switchMap(owner => this.put(owner))
        .scan((acc, val) => {
          console.log('val ' + val.name);
          console.log('acc.count ' + acc.length);
          acc.push(val);
          return acc; }
        , [])
        .do(owners => console.log('4 ' + owners.length))
        .do(owners => console.log('5 ' + owners[0].name));
}

put(value: IItem): Observable<IItem> {
    return Observable.create((observer: Observer<IItem>) => {
        this.getDb().subscribe(db => {
            const request = db.transaction(this.storeName, 'readwrite').objectStore(this.storeName).put(value.populateValue());
            request.onerror = (e) => {
                observer.error(e);
            };
            request.onsuccess = (e) => {
                if (this.storeName === 'owner') {
                    console.log(value);
                }

                const idbRequest = e.target as IDBRequest;
                value.id = idbRequest.result;
                observer.next(value);
                observer.complete();
            };
        });
    });
}
```

Data it produces:

```
OwnerModel {gameId: 47, age: 50, name: "Leo Bates", isUser: false}
OwnerModel {gameId: 47, age: 15, name: "Nicolas Baker", isUser: false}
OwnerModel {gameId: 47, age: 41, name: "Nicolas Lee", isUser: false}
OwnerModel {gameId: 47, age: 21, name: "Carl Taylor", isUser: false}
OwnerModel {gameId: 47, age: 37, name: "Grace Nelson", isUser: false}
OwnerModel {gameId: 47, age: 5, name: "Ervin Pierce", isUser: false}
OwnerModel {gameId: 47, age: 36, name: "Sammy Walker", isUser: false}
OwnerModel {gameId: 47, age: 2, name: "Jean Gibbs", isUser: false}
OwnerModel {gameId: 47, age: 1, name: "Chris Garrett", isUser: false}
OwnerModel {gameId: 47, age: 18, name: "Todd Moss", isUser: false}
```

Logs:

```
...
2 Jean Gibbs
3 Jean Gibbs
put Jean Gibbs
put.finished Jean Gibbs
2 Chris Garrett
3 Chris Garrett
put Chris Garrett
put.finished Chris Garrett
2 Todd Moss
3 Todd Moss
put Todd Moss
put.finished Todd Moss
val Todd Moss
acc.count 0
4 1
5 Todd Moss
length 1
```

[Paste Bin](https://jsbin.com/zenubejaho/edit?html,js,console) I've extracted what I think is a simplified working version of the code into a paste bin.  VS Code is giving me a number of compile errors when I try and do this.  @mayflower thank you for your input, I need to work out why it's not letting me implement your solution - I'm sure I'm doing something silly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated with sample working code**

scan operator will accumulate as array till input observable stream is is completed. when a new stream comes it will create a new array

here in the put method you are sending a new observable every time which is getting completed after emitting one value. hence scan operator behaves as it should be by finishing accumulation of values

to solve this change the put method to return o (without converting to observable) and use map instead of switchMap to return value as it is

from

```
public put(ownerModel: OwnerModel): Observable<OwnerModel> {
   console.log('put ' + ownerModel.name);
   const  o = this.storageModel.put(ownerModel);
   console.log('put.finished ' + ownerModel.name);
   return o as Observable<OwnerModel>;
}

.do(owner => console.log('3 ' + (owner as OwnerModel).name))
.switchMap(owner => this.put(owner))
.scan((acc, val) => {
```

To

```
public put(ownerModel: OwnerModel): Observable<OwnerModel> {
   console.log('put ' + ownerModel.name);
   const  o = this.storageModel.put(ownerModel);
   console.log('put.finished ' + ownerModel.name);
   return o;
}

.do(owner => console.log('3 ' + (owner as OwnerModel).name))
.map(owner => this.put(owner))
.scan((acc, val) => {
```

this should solve the problem

Below is the sample code for your refernce

```
checkScan() {
    const source = range(0, 10);

    const example = source.pipe(
      map(value1 => value1 + 1),
      map(value2 => value2 * 2),
      map(val => {
        let o: Object = { data: val };
        return o;
      }),
      scan((acc: Array<{}>, curr: {}) => {
        acc.push(curr);
        return acc;
      }, [])
    );
    // log accumulated values
    const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
    // output:
    // ...
    //"[{"data":2},{"data":4},{"data":6},{"data":8},{"data":10},{"data":12},{"data":14},{"data":16},{"data":18},{"data":20}]"
  }
```

Comment: mayflower thank you for the response.  Ideally I would like the result of the put method as this will have the id of the newly put-ed item which I'd like for the store.  I have added the put method code on there.  I believe it is a hot observable and hope to have confirmed this by the logging as the data in the original post is generated from the logging in the put method.

Comment: @SimonHoulton updated my answer, the root cause still the same

Comment: thank you again.  I've tried to apply your answer but I'm getting a compile error: Type Observable<Observable<OwnerModel[]>> is not assignable to type Observable<OwnerModel>.  What I don't understand is why a hot Observable, the 3rd method in the original post is giving the appearance of running in a different thread.  To me it looks like you can't have nested Observable.creates and have them return each item.

Comment: have modified your JS Bin and scan is working as expected link<https://jsbin.com/qatizohewe/1/edit?js>